Why do C++ Thrift TLS socket operations throw exception with multiple openssl error codes?
We use Thrift C++ TLS socket for data exchanging. The openssl is built with the no-err option. We wrap every code snippet calling thrift RPC by try-catch and log the exception message. In the development phase, we used to see exceptions thrown by Thrift, that contain only a single openssl error in the message like:
SSL_CTX_new: SSL error # 168558848
SSL_connect: SSL error # 167772294 (SSL_error_code = 1)

But after the mass deployment, we observed some exceptions that contain multiple openssl errors in the message, like:
SSL_CTX_new: SSL error # 50856204; SSL error # 478150863; SSL error # 301989996; SSL error # 50856204; SSL error # 478150863; SSL error # 301989996; SSL error # 168558848
SSL_connect: SSL error # 33554570; SSL error # 33554546; SSL error # 478674948; SSL error # 109576198; SSL error # 167772294 (SSL_error_code = 1)

Digging the Thrift code we found this function is used to build the exception message:
void buildErrors(string& errors, int errno_copy, int sslerrno) {
  unsigned long errorCode;
  char message[256];

  errors.reserve(512);
  while ((errorCode = ERR_get_error()) != 0) {
    if (!errors.empty()) {
      errors += "; ";
    }
    const char* reason = ERR_reason_error_string(errorCode);
    if (reason == NULL) {
      THRIFT_SNPRINTF(message, sizeof(message) - 1, "SSL error # %lu", errorCode);
      reason = message;
    }
    errors += reason;
  }
  // ...
}

Doesn't Thrift code throw immediately if an openssl error is raised? How could multiple errors get queued for the thread of execution?
